# What types/namespaces shouldn't be renamed?

Tags: .net, reflection, clr, mono.cecil

I'm new to Cecil and I created a simple test. It renames all namespaces/types to random strings.

```
var assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(@"C:\somexe.exe");
foreach (var t in assembly.MainModule.Types) {
    t.Namespace = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    t.Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();               
}
```

After starting the executable runs, but with empty form (it's winforms).

I thought CLR doesn't care about names? What I shouldn't rename? Or I'm doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of things, esecially in winforms, rely on reflection. And reflection cares very much about names. This could also relate to resources, and a resource file not matching up. Also, a lot of attributes may include type information as strings, which can impact things. As can serialization (BinaryFormatter in particular).

However, without more context (mainly: code), we can only guess.

Comment: I think it's resources. The resource name must match the namespace.class name. What about attributes then? I shouldn't rename them too?

Comment: @blez actually, I meant the values inside attributes; many such as TypeDescriptorAttribute etc can optionally store type information as a literal string (instead of via typeof). If that literal string no longer matches the old name...